# Xpath expression to access parent or sibling using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath module

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I want to select parent or sibling of a node using HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath Perl module, Lets take a sample HTML as follows:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="c1">Match_Text</td>
        <td class="c2">Extact_Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="c1"></td>
        <td class="c2"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I want to extract text "Match_Text" for this I give xpath expression as:

```
'/html/body//td[@class="c1"]="Match_Text"/../td[@class="c2"]'
```

which is a valid expression for my use case.

But looks like going to parent not implement and I get following error from perl module:

> axis axis_parent not implemented [Can't locate object method
>   "getParentNode" via package "XML::XPathEngine::Literal" at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/XML/XPathEngine/Step.pm line 326. ]

Can anyone suggest an alternate Xpath expression that may work for my use case (accessing parent/sibling of a node). Note that I want to do this only using Xpath expression and dont want to create a DOM and explicitly traverse the tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. The problem isn't lack of support, it's that you're trying to find the parent of the boolean returned by the comparison. It doesn't have one.

You could use

```
//*[ td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"] ]/td[@class="c2"]

//td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"]/following-sibling::*

//td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"]/following-sibling::td[@class="c2"]

//td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"]/../td[@class="c2"]
```

Comment: XML::XPathEngine implements `getChildNodes` as `sub getChildNodes { return wantarray ? () : []; }`, so it doesn't give you an error there, even though it makes no sense to get the children of a litteral. So I could add `getParentNode` with the same content, or have it die with an error (and do the same with `getChildNodes` and `getAttributes`) which is probably more helpful for the user. Any opinion on the subject?

Comment: @mirod, Dieing with useful message sounds better to me than never matching.

Comment: OK, I just released a new version that dies in all cases, with a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any working expressions like that before. Actually, I think the error is due to that expression not being well composed and parsable.

Anyway, here are two alternatives for your goal – though not tested with the specified Perl module:

`//td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"]/../td[@class="c2"]`
`//td[@class="c2" and ../td[@class="c1" and text()="Match_Text"]]`

Tested on [shell-tools](http://www.shell-tools.net/) and [online-toolz](http://www.online-toolz.com/).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to select parent or sibling of a node using
>   HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath Perl module.

In any case when you want to have an XPath expression that selects several nodes and you know a separate XPath expression for every node of these, you can simply use the standard XPath union operator `|` as below:

```
 (/*/body//*[td[@class="c1"and . = 'Match_Text']])[1]
|
  (/*/body//*[td[@class="c1"and . = 'Match_Text']])[1]
               /td[[@class="c1"and not(. = 'Match_Text')]
```

In this XPath expression the first operand of the `|` operator is the parent element of the reference node and the second argument of the union operator is an expression that selects all children elements of this parent, whose string value is different from that of the reference node.

The result is that the union of the two node-sets is selected.